Проверка сайта на наличие горизонтального скролла при масштабировании страницы до 200%
Сейчас я занимаюсь автоматизацией проверок сайтов на доступность для незрячих пользователей.У меня возникли проблемы с проверкой на наличие горизонтального скролла при масштабировании до 200%. Мой код на JS определяет точно только его отсутствие, а вот с наличием не получается. Ситуация усложняется тем, что я не разбираюсь в CSS и HTML, с JS работаю тоже немного, поэтому по паре ответов ChatGPT я понял, что на горизонтальный скролл могут влиять стили CSS. Я хочу узнать, что может конкретно влиять на отображение горизонтального скролла при масштабировании и как его можно скрывать, соответственно так я смогу узнать, что мне надо добавить в код, чтобы максимально точно определять наличие горизонтального скролла при масштабировании до 200%

Да всё это CSS, а точнее какие-то элементы у вас становятся настолько огромными, что не помещаются. Таблицы вообще не поддаются бесконечному уменьшению. Если хотите что бы не было горизонтального скролла - можете прописать в body overflow-x: hidden, но учтите, что элементы выходящие за грань экрана тоже обрежутся шириной экрана и будут не доступны для просмотра

Например картинка 1000px будет помещаться, но увеличив на 200% она станет 2000px и уже не будет помещаться. Таким образом нужно проверить все элементы. Я обычно нахожу эти элементы открыв в Chrome - F12 и нажав Ctrl + Shift + С - мышкой нахожу эти элементы, что не помещаются и их исправляю при помощи CSS

проблема в том, что я проверяю не один сайт, а 500-1000)
поэтому я использую node.js и puppeteer. Поэтому пытаюсь выяснить, что надо учитывать, чтобы код работал правильно на как можно большем количестве сайтов

Я же написал элементы HTML не помещаются в ширину экрана. Значит вам нужно узнавать ширину экрана 1920px скажем и например + 200% = 1920 / 2 = 960px и теперь вы должны узнать ширину тегов типа ,  и т.д. И потом посмотреть какие из них больше 960px. Вот эти самые и не помещаются. Правда там может быть совокупность двух элементов внутри этого быть проблемой переполнения, но уже будет понятно откуда копать.
